# Qt: How do text editors perform the Replace operation and stop once they cycle back to the first replacement they ever performed?

Tags: c++, qt, replace, qt5, text-editor

I'm working on a [text editor project](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor) in Qt, and I'm currently trying to imitate the Find and Replace behavior of text editors and word processors.

Consider this example from Microsoft Word, with the numbers indicating the cursor position/index at the end of each line:

> hello 5
>
> matey 11
>
> hello 17

In other words, if the cursor is at the very start of the document (to the left of "hello"), its index will be 0. To the right of the first "h", it will be 1. And so on. This is how Qt treats cursor positions within a `QTextEdit` (or, in this case, a `QPlainTextEdit`).

Suppose our cursor is currently positioned right after "matey," at position 11, and that we've opened the Find dialog (with Ctrl+F or the menu action).

In a word processor like Microsoft Word, the search for "hello" would proceed to find the bottom "hello" at position 17, then cycle back to the top and find the first "hello" at position 5, and then stop searching as soon as it cycles back to the position where it found its very first match (17). This makes sense—you wouldn't want to keep cycling the user through the whole document and giving the impression that you're finding "new" hits when you really aren't.

Moreover, when you exit the search, your cursor will return to its initial position prior to the first search you conducted for the term in question (that is, the cursor will return to position 11 and will not remain at position 17, the "false positive" new find).

This behavior is expected and works as intended in my own text editor. The relevant portions of code to examine are as follows:

- [on_findQueryText_ready](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/blob/master/CustomTextEditor/editor.cpp#L107) in editor.cpp
- [finddialog.h](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/blob/master/CustomTextEditor/finddialog.h)
- [finddialog.cpp](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/blob/master/CustomTextEditor/finddialog.cpp)

Let me explain my own approach before describing the problem in more detail:

The `FindDialog` class keeps a map associating each search query/term with a pair of positions/integers: the first integer is the position the cursor was at prior to the first search for that term (using our example, 11); the second integer in the pair is the position at which the first match was found (using our example, that would be 17).

The search proceeds until the end of the document. If a match is not found, it does another search from the start of the document. If we end up at a [position equal to the first match](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/blob/master/CustomTextEditor/editor.cpp#L155), we treat it as a "find failure", reset our search history, and return.

Now onto the Replace operation, which first calls the Find operation and then inserts the replacement text at the cursor positioned by the Find operation. See [this line](https://github.com/AleksandrHovhannisyan/User-Friendly-Text-Editor/blob/master/CustomTextEditor/finddialog.cpp#L99).

Here's the problem: with the **Replace** operation, suppose we search for "hello" and try to replace it with "hellos". First, we'll replace the bottom "hello" with "hellos". So far so good. Then we'll replace the top "hello" with "hellos". And then we cycle back to the bottom "hello". But here's the problem: our cursor is no longer at position 17, because the insertion of "hellos" at the top of the document just shifted all the indices/cursor positions up by 1. That is, the index to the very right of the bottom "hello" will be 18, not 17. Here's some debugging code that confirms this behavior:

[image]

The reason I mention this is because there's a workaround I could use where I set some sort of flag in the Editor—canReplace—that's checked before replacing content. This flag would get set to false whenever we cycle back to the first Find match. Of course, when I tested this, it doesn't work because of the cursor positions shifting like I described above.

Is there a cleaner or better solution that I'm just not thinking of? I know this was a really long post, but I'd appreciate any help. Thank you to those who read this all :)

Comment: Maybe store the [QTextBlock](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html) after doing a Replace into your pool of ReplacedInstances. Then everytime you do findNext and move the cursor, [get the text block underneath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#block) and [perform an equality check](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html#operator-eq-eq)?

Comment: can I propose you to remove the tag C++ please ? nothing in your question is associated to C++

Comment: No problem, done

Comment: Not having read everything in detail, but usually a text model doesn't conceptually work well with fixed positions. For example a range of text (eg. a selection) shouldn't be stored by fixed positions outside the API since if the underlying text is updated the text range ' object ' should hold the same - also the case the if text is changed inside the range then the range has to reflect that. I know you asking how the internals work, but that is sort of same side of the coin.

Comment: @bruno the c ++ tag is relevant, Qt is a library that provides support for several languages such as QML, c++, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, but what is the difference if I replace the tag C++ by Java ? nothing, so the tag is not relevant, just my 2 cents

Comment: @bruno It is relevant since natively the Qt Widgets refer to C ++, and the implementations that are used as a solution will be based on that language.